# Windows/WINS host names not working even after winbind install on 16.04

Tags: networking, windows, lan

In the past, I was able to get Windows host names on the LAN resolving from inside Ubuntu by doing `sudo apt-get install winbind` and then editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (adding `wins` to the end of the `hosts:` line). It appears in Ubuntu 16.04 (actually using Xubuntu 16.04), this is no longer sufficient.

Example output:

```
me@myubuntumachine:~$ ping mywindowsmachine
ping: unknown host mywindowsmachine
```

(tags: NetBIOS WINS)

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this myself and the problem seems to be a missing `libnss_wins.so` library, and I checked into how to ensure this exists on my machine and I found `sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind` and doing that fixed the problem immediately.

More info: I checked into what was going on by capturing output from `strace ping mywindowsmachine` and the problem was easy to spot as the program was trying to find a file that just wasn't there, `libnss_wins.so.2`. This showed a potential solution of simply ensuring that file is present. Below is the strace output truncated to show only lines concerning a search for this `libnss_wins.so.2` file, and the important thing here is that every single attempt to find the file fails, right up to the last. On my other Ubuntu machine, I compared the same `strace` output, and there it succeeded on maybe the fourth or fifth try:

```
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=69632, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7ffd56786e80)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffd56786e80)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd56786e80) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libnss_wins.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```